# Redirect during validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

Sometimes inside FluentValidation validator I need to make redirect if state is incorrect (for example, I find that being deleted entity already does not exist and I redirect to the list of entities). Is validator a right place for this kind of logic? If yes, how can I RedirectToAction, RedirectToRoute, etc. from validator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, validation shouldn't control UI flow.

Normally something like this is appropriate inside of your controller:

```
if( !ModelState.IsValid )
  return RedirectToAction();
```